# iOS 8.x app is crashing in background launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushkit

I am developing an VoIP iOS app using PushKit. After getting PushKit payload message, app supposed to be launched in background state. After receiving payload, I am initiating a socket and connecting it with the server. Everything works fine on iOS 9+  devices. But I have iPhone 5c (iOS 8.1)device on which the app crashes. I am not able to figure out the cause of crash.

[image: This stack trace I am getting after crash]

Comment: Can you check the XCode logs after the app crashes. It is very difficult to understand from this.

Comment: No, not getting any logs related crash.

Comment: Any change you can get the crashlog from iTunesConnect (use Xcode organizer).